# How to authenticate socket.io connection in nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am working on a chat application where socket is used for bi-directional sharing of messages.

The socket currently works fine but I want to be able to authenticate user before they can have access to the socket connection. I have trying to use passport but it would seem there is something I am not doing right as I get the error `No session found`.

```
const createError = require("http-errors");
const express = require("express");
const { join } = require("path");
const logger = require("morgan");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const SequelizeStore = require("connect-session-sequelize")(session.Store);
const db = require("./db");
const { User } = require("./db/models");
const passport = require('passport');
// create store for sessions to persist in database
const sessionStore = new SequelizeStore({ db });
const http = require("http");
const db = require("../db");
const onlineUsers = require("../onlineUsers");
const passportSocketIo = require('passport.socketio');

const { json, urlencoded } = express;

const app = express();

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(json());
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
  genid:(req)=>{
    return req.cookies
  },
  secret:  process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: true,
  store: sessionStore,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  
  const token = req.cookies["messenger-token"];

  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SESSION_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        return next();
      }
      User.findOne({
        where: { id: decoded.id },
      }).then((user) => {
        req.user = user;
        return next();
      });
    });
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});



app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "3001");
app.set("port", port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces, and sync database.
 */

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT"],
    credentials: true
  }
});



io.use(
  passportSocketIo.authorize({
    cookieParser: cookieParser,
    key: 'messenger-token',
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    store: sessionStore,
    success: onAuthorizeSuccess,
    fail: onAuthorizeFail
  })
);

function onAuthorizeSuccess(data, accept) {
  console.log('successful connection to socket.io');

  accept(null, true);
}

function onAuthorizeFail(data, message, error, accept) {
  if (error) throw new Error(message);
  console.log('failed connection to socket.io:', message);
  accept(null, false);
}


io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // console.log(`USER ${JSON.stringify(socket)}`);
  socket.on("go-online", (id) => {
  
    if (!onlineUsers.includes(id)) {
      onlineUsers.push(id);
    }
    // send the user who just went online to everyone else who is already online
    socket.broadcast.emit("add-online-user", id);
  });

  socket.on("new-message", (data) => {
    
    socket.broadcast.emit("new-message", {
      message: data.message,
      sender: data.sender,
    });
  });

  socket.on("read-message", (data) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("read-message", data);
  });

  socket.on("read-messages", (data) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("read-messages", data);
  });

  socket.on("logout", (id) => {
    if (onlineUsers.includes(id)) {
      userIndex = onlineUsers.indexOf(id);
      onlineUsers.splice(userIndex, 1);
      socket.broadcast.emit("remove-offline-user", id);
    }
  });
});
```

How can I authenticate user with socket. Feel free to suggest other method aside using passport.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error in [Github](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio/issues/146) and it hasn't been resolved yet.

According to [the official document](https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/) (see "Compatibility with Express middleware" section), you can use express middleware in `io.use` by using `wrap`.

```
const wrap = middleware => (socket, next) => middleware(socket.request, {}, next);
```

The section shows how to use "express-session" module with socket.io. I guess this way is better for you because you already use it.